# BeautifulSoup & Selenium - Incorrect data copied to my spreadsheet after Exception

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

First time posting, constructive criticism welcome.

I'm trying to automate a market analysis task for my company. I wrote a program which executes fine under most circumstances but stopped working once I added an exception to deal with a zip code request. Now BeautifulSoup seems to be loading the incorrect source page and cannot find the data I need.

I've tried updating the link variable which BeautifulSoup is gathering the source from, but that doesn't seem to be working.

```py
# Global variables
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\caleb.grauberger\Desktop\Scripts\Market Analysis for GSA')
WB_ORIG = openpyxl.load_workbook("test_pricelist.xlsx")
SHEET_ORIG = WB_ORIG['Sheet1']
MAX_ROW = SHEET_ORIG.max_row
NEW_WB_NAME = 'market_analysis_test.xlsx'


def pricelist_manip():

    # Note: This is the starting row number for the next for loop
    r = 2
    wb_new = openpyxl.load_workbook(NEW_WB_NAME)
    sheet_new = wb_new.active

    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\selenium\drivers")
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\caleb.grauberger\Desktop\Scripts\Market Analysis for GSA')

    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    driver.get("https://www.gsaadvantage.gov/advantage/main/start_page.do")
    driver.maximize_window()

    for i in range(2, MAX_ROW):
        """Copies the value of the Manufacturer's part number and pastes it into the search box"""
        start_time = time.time()

        driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
        item_id = SHEET_ORIG.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys(item_id)
        driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        product_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Click to view product details']/following::a[1]")
        print(i - 1)
        print(item_id)
        links_list = []

        for values in product_links:
            """Creates a list of hyperlinks for each product on the page."""
            hyperlink = values.get_attribute("href")
            links_list.append(hyperlink)

        for x in range(len(links_list)):
            """Goes through the links_list one by one. During each iteration, 
            the program goes to the link, copies the necessary information
            to the spreadsheet, and moves on."""
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
            driver.get(links_list[x])

            # Sometimes a link will bring up an option to enter ZIP Code. This deals with that.

            try:
                driver.find_element_by_id("zip").clear()
                driver.find_element_by_id("zip").send_keys('91911')
                driver.find_element_by_id("zip").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                time.sleep(1)
                driver.get(links_list[x])
            except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                pass


            rows = r

            source = requests.get(links_list[x]).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
            body = soup.find('body')
            try:
                part_num = body.find('td', width="78%").text
            except AttributeError:
                print("AttributeError: Contractor Part Number defaulted")
                part_num = item_id
            finally:
                comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

                for comment in comments:
                    """Iterates over html searching for contractor names. Then writes contractor names to xlsx"""
                    if comment.strip() == 'Contractor display':
                        contractor = comment.find_next_sibling('td')
                        sheet_new['C' + str(r)] = contractor.text
                        sheet_new['A' + str(r)] = item_id
                        sheet_new['B' + str(r)] = part_num
                        r += 1

                r = rows

                for comment in comments:
                    if comment.strip() == 'unit price':
                        """Iterates over html searching for prices. Then writes prices to xlsx"""
                        price = comment.find_next_sibling('td')
                        sheet_new['D' + str(r)] = price.text
                        r += 1

                r = rows + 3
                time.sleep(1)

        wb_new.save(NEW_WB_NAME)

        # This checks the runtime of the loop
        end_time = time.time()
        duration = end_time - start_time
        duration = round(duration, 2)
        print("Runtime for this iteration was {} seconds.\n".format(duration))
        time.sleep(2)

    wb_new.save(NEW_WB_NAME)
    wb_new.close()
```

I am expecting the code to output the following for each price listing per item:

```
Part # - Contractor Part # - Contractor Name - Price
```

The example I'm having trouble with is when searching for `DF2-850-FDPO-KH-S-R`. There are five offers which are normally recorded smoothly. In the code above, no results are recorded.

Comment: as a start, `MAX_ROW` is not defined.

Comment: and could you give us a part number so we can see how the target page looks like?

Comment: Hello, I didn't add the Global Variables above to try and limit the amount of code I posted. I just edited the original post to show the global variables as well. 

As far as an item number which is causing the issue to occur, try `DF2-850-FDPO-KH-S-R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion which takes benefits from `pandas`(you can easily export to excel later on)

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#A panda dataframe where all results will get stored
global_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['gsin','Part #', 'Contractor Part #', 'Contractor Name', 'Price','Deliv days',  'Min Order', 'FOB/Shipping'])

part = "MCMS00001"
driver.get("https://www.gsaadvantage.gov/advantage/main/start_page.do")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
element.send_keys(part)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav-submit-input').click()


#Find links
html = driver.page_source
soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
links = soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('gsin='))
links = list(set([x.get('href') for x in links]))

#Explore links
for link in links:
    driver.get("https://www.gsaadvantage.gov"+link)

    #Sometimes zip pages shows up
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("zip")
        element.send_keys("91911")
        driver.find_element_by_name('submit').click()
    except:
        pass

    html = driver.page_source
    soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')

    #Get the table with the expected elements
    table = soup.find('table', {'class':'greybox'})
    item_numbers = []

    #Extract itemNumbers
    for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:]: #skip the header line
        item_number = tr.find('a', href=re.compile('itemNumber='))

        if item_number != None:
            pattern = 'itemNumber=(.*?)\&'        
            item_numbers.append(re.findall(pattern, item_number.get('href'))[0])

    #Store table into a dataframe
    temp_df = pd.read_html(str(soup.find('table', {'class':'greybox'})))[0]

    #EDIT START : handle missing columns
    for x in [2,8,14,16,18]:
        if x not in temp_df.columns:
            temp_df[x] = ""

    temp_df = temp_df[[2,8,14,16,18]].dropna(how='all')
    temp_df = temp_df[1:]
    temp_df.columns = ['Price', 'Contractor Name', 'Deliv days',  'Min Order', 'FOB/Shipping']
    temp_df['Contractor Part #'] = item_numbers
    temp_df['Part #'] = part

    #Extracting gsin from the explored link which differs in case of multiple links
    gsin = link.split("gsin=")[1]
    temp_df['gsin'] = gsin

    temp_df = temp_df[['gsin','Part #', 'Contractor Part #', 'Contractor Name', 'Price','Deliv days',  'Min Order', 'FOB/Shipping']]


    #EDIT END
    #Append new results to the global dataframe
    global_df = pd.concat([global_df, temp_df])
```

Finally the global_df dataframe looks like this:

```
+---+----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   |      gsin      |  Part #   |         Contractor Part #         |    Contractor Name    |  Price  |      Deliv days       |     Min Order      |    FOB/Shipping    |
+---+----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1 | 11000058164089 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REGX-XXL   | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |                    |
| 1 | 11000058164195 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REG-L      | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | NaN                | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |
| 3 | 11000058164195 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MILREG-L       | Blue Water Sales, LLC | $176.47 | 14 days shipped ARO   | $100.00            | D-CONUS/O-AK,PR,HI |
| 1 | 11000063336537 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001                         | o                     | $153.99 | $50.00                | D-CONUSND-AK,PR,HI | NaN                |
| 3 | 11000063336537 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001                         | s dv                  | $157.16 | $50.00                | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   | NaN                |
| 1 | 11000058164083 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REG-S      | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | NaN                | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |
| 3 | 11000058164083 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MILREG-S       | Blue Water Sales, LLC | $176.47 | 14 days shipped ARO   | $100.00            | D-CONUS/O-AK,PR,HI |
| 1 | 11000058163538 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REG-M      | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | NaN                | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |
| 3 | 11000058163538 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MILREG-M       | Blue Water Sales, LLC | $176.47 | 14 days shipped ARO   | $100.00            | D-CONUS/O-AK,PR,HI |
| 1 | 11000058163624 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REG-XS     | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | NaN                | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |
| 3 | 11000058163624 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MILREG-XS      | Blue Water Sales, LLC | $176.47 | 14 days shipped ARO   | $100.00            | D-CONUS/O-AK,PR,HI |
| 1 | 11000058163625 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REGXX-XXXL | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |                    |
| 1 | 11000058163763 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MIL-REG-XL     | UNIFIRE INC           | $154.15 | 30 days delivered ARO | NaN                | O-CONUS,AK,PR,HI   |
| 3 | 11000058163763 | MCMS00001 | MCMS00001-MULCM-V54MILREG-XL      | Blue Water Sales, LLC | $176.47 | 14 days shipped ARO   | $100.00            | D-CONUS/O-AK,PR,HI |
+---+----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for your reply. Not all heroes wear capes! 

I know pandas is the preferred method, I am just not familiar with it at all. I just tried it out and it is working for me. I will expand the selection and work a bit more with it.

Comment: Sebastien D - I'm running into an issue now where the table of data which is being pulled from in the HTML varies in size depending on the item searched. This is throwing an error in the program due to the indexes not matching. As an example, this item: `MCMS00001`. Any suggestions? I was thinking of using the index of the top bar of the HTML table as a reference point for the data I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in the FOB/Shipping column or you don't mind?

Comment: For what I'm analyzing, that column doesn't matter. The essential columns are `Part Num - Contractor Name - Price`. Anything else isn't necessary for what we need the info for.

Comment: Edited answer. Please note most of the data is extracted with some rare exceptions